# Spatie laravel-permission package

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-permission

I am currently working on my diploma thesis and I would like to ask you if you have any idea how should be implemented this senario :

I have 3 roles in my website and I want to give  to role "User" his permissions and roles just for specific time -> 2 monhts or etc. Could you give me any advice how to do it ? I am using the laravel-permission package by spatie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create role_expire table, When you assign role to user for 2 months, new RoleExpireMiddleware that you create will check if role expired or not.

Comment: Hello thank you for your valuable answer,:) I will try that and I am thinking maybe about painfull thing, but maybe it would be better to create permissions for certain time. In many scenarios they have to give more permissions for just one Month and then they want to take that permission from the role. Thank you for the advice :) I will let this question open and when I will solve it I will update here the solution. Maybe someone will come with something better :)